# Get Simcard Information like Phone Number, carrier..

Tags: android

Is there any way to access the mobile number and carrier name that the device is currently using ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure that asking google.com will take less time than writing the question on SO

Comment: @Xakku - you seem to be saying you'd like people here to volunteer to be a *human powered search engine* for you.  There are already many posts on this topic, elsewhere and even here, which you can find with simple searching.

Answer (score 2):

All the information available about the telephony provider can be found within the TelephonyManager class, you get a reference of it as follows:

```
TelephonyManager tm = Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)
```

This are the methods available for sim status:

```
String   getSimCountryIso()
//Returns the ISO country code equivalent for the SIM provider's country code.
String   getSimOperator()
//Returns the MCC+MNC (mobile country code + mobile network code) of the provider of the SIM.
String   getSimOperatorName()
//Returns the Service Provider Name (SPN).
String   getSimSerialNumber()
//Returns the serial number of the SIM, if applicable.
int  getSimState()
//Returns a constant indicating the state of the device SIM card.
```

Look at google's doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html
for more information about the different methods provided.

Regards!

Comment: what if vendor is not offering the service ?? That means my carrier is not to provide simcard detail. we still can access the phone no. ?

Comment: Yes, you can get all the information available from this class...